# Difference between role of Interfaces and <type> in di.xml

Tags: magento2

I have one query regarding the understanding in role of interface `<preference>` and `<type>` attributes that are used in di.xml. Under which instances we should use `<preference>` and `<type>` ? Does there any solid difference in terms of logical implementation.

E.g go to app/code/Magento/Catalog/etc/di.xml, there would be lot of instances where `<preference>` and `<type>` tags are used. How exactly we can distinguish between them ?

Looking forward to hear thoughts.

Comment: You can understand and get more information from here : [http://www.eschrade.com/page/basic-configuring-the-magento-2-dependency-injection-container/](http://www.eschrade.com/page/basic-configuring-the-magento-2-dependency-injection-container/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<preference>` is used to [indicate which concrete class you want the DI framework to supply when that type is requested](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/extension-dev-guide/depend-inj.html#dep-inj-mod).

`<type>` is used for a couple of different things, one of which is to supply or override arguments that are injected into the constructor of a concrete type.  The `<type>` declaration is also [used to declare plugins](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/extension-dev-guide/plugins.html#plugin-declare).

The time you see an interface in both the `<preference>` and the `<type>` is when a plugin is being defined for that interface.  `<type>` allows you to declare a plugin on that object type, whether it is a concrete class or an interface.

Example from [`app/code/Magento/Catalog/etc/di.xml`](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/develop/app/code/Magento/Catalog/etc/di.xml):

```
<preference for="Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface" type="Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductRepository" />
...
<type name="Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface">
    <plugin name="transactionWrapper" type="\Magento\Catalog\Model\Plugin\ProductRepository\TransactionWrapper" sortOrder="-1"/>
</type>
```

Comment: This raises two questions for me. How can I decide where to use plugin and where to you preference in my custom module? Can you put some light on it.